# How to convert a column of lists to a column of strings python

Tags: python, pandas, string

I am accessing data from an API and it returned a column of data that consists one single or two item lists, like so:

EDIT: This is a pandas series.

```
['WR'],
 ['RB'],
 ['QB'],
 ['QB'],
 ['TE'],
 ['TE'],
 ['TE'],
 ['WR', 'RB'],
 ['QB'],
 ['WR'],
 ['WR'],
 ['WR'],
 ['TE'],
 ['TE'],
 ['TE'],
 ['WR'],
 ['WR'],
 ['WR'],
 ['WR'],
 ['RB'],
 ['RB'],
 ['WR', 'RB'],
 ['WR']
...
```

And so on. What I would like to do is to simply convert each list to a string, like so:

```
'WR',
 'RB',
 'QB',
 'QB',
 'TE',
 'TE',
 'TE',
 'WR, RB',
...
```

And so on. I tried [.explode()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html) but this isn't exactly what I want because I don't want the lists with two items to make a new row for the second item. I also tried simply indexing it using `[1:-1]` but obviously that didn't work since the brackets aren't characters in the string. I appreciate any help. Thanks!

Comment: Is your input a pandas Series?  Try using `', '.join`

Comment: Yes @ScottBoston

Answer (score 6):

Let us try

```
s.str.join(',')

Out[249]: 
0       RB
1       QB
2       QB
3    WR,TE
dtype: object
```

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

s = pd.Series([['RB'],['QB'],['QB'], ['WR','TE']])

s.map(', '.join)
```

Output:

```
0        RB
1        QB
2        QB
3    WR, TE
dtype: object
```

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
List=[', '.join(r) for r in List]
```